# Add a chapter for \listoflistings

Tags: minted

I've struggled for some time to get the `\listoflistings` to work. 
I'm using minted to insert code-examples like this:

```
\begin{listing}[H]
\inputminted[mathescape,linenos,frame=single,resetmargins=true]{js}{code/local-storage-sample.txt}

\caption{Enhancement for the LocalStorage to directly store \& retrieve \acf{JS}-Objects }
\label{code:ls-sample}
\end{listing}
```

In the end of my Thesis I have:

```
\clearpage\listoffigures
\clearpage\listoftables

% Das Quellcodeverzeichnis
\chapter{List of Listings}
\renewcommand{\listoflistings}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoflistingscaption}%
  \listof{listing}{\listoflistingscaption}%
}
\listoflistings
```

From the styling and everything this suits my needs, but I would need only one more thing: Add the `\listoflistings` to the TOC as "List of Listings" either without the `\chapter` or by telling the ListOfListings to use no Heading.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't see why you need the `\chapter{List of Listings}` at all

Comment: Doing this is quite easy; just use the option `newfloat` of the `minted` package: `\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}`